# Link a wordpress custom post to a woocommerce product

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on something where users need to complete a very long form in order to purchase a specific product. I'm using caldera forms to create the form and allow users to manage their entries.

And in the form I have included an `add to cart` button for the product.

How can I link the product to the entry created when it was added to the cart and display it as such in order meta and emails?